# Setting up Syntastic for Android Java development

Tags: java, android, vim, syntastic

I'm trying to use VIM and Syntastic for Java Android development. 
I am getting lots of 'package does not exist' and 'cannot find symbol' errors.
I've tried setting my class path in .vimrc using

`let g:syntastic_java_javac_config_file_enabled=1
let g:syntastic_java_javac_classpath = "path/to/sdk:path/to/project/app/libs"`

However still getting the errors come up from Syntastic in Vim. Android Studio shows no errors, project builds fine.

I'd like to use Vim for editing and Android Studio for building and imports etc.

I've tried running `javac` on the file and get the same errors, perhaps I need to add paths to the CLASSPATH environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

This [link](http://ncona.com/2014/03/configure-syntastic-to-work-fine-with-android-projects/) will help you on the problem.

**Note:** In my case, adding `/<path to android-sdk>/platforms/android-21/*.jar` to `SyntasticJavacEditClasspath` will still complain on the on android.support.v7 since it is in my gradle dependencies list instead.